# TYPO3: Change the font size of links in File Collection

Tags: html, css, typo3

I have a TYPO3 site with links to company documents. Since some file collections can be quite long I would like to make the font of the links smaller for specific pages.

I can set up a custom html file with links to files, and edit the font size, but that would invalidate the file collections.

How do I change the font size of the file collection links for specific pages only?

Answer (score 2):

First: To change the font size, CSS is the best way to do this.

Second: If you only want to change specific pages, you need to be able to change class or id of that pages.

Solution: In a content element, you can change the `layout` of a content element, which effectively changes a class which is wrapped around the content element. Just test it by selecting another `layout` and see the class changing.
If you use a specific `layout` selection and change the content elements you want to change the font size, you can add this class to CSS.

Comment: Is there a simple way to change the existing layout or to add a new layout? I'm not a typo3 integrator... THX!

Comment: You can easily add it in TSconfig with `TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.addItems.100 = New item` or just change the label with `TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.altLabels.2 = Another label for item 2`. See: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

Comment: Still didn't figure it out. I understand what should be done, but I just cannot figure it out. Is there a step-by-step tutorial to make changes like font size or template default colour?

Comment: Also, I see that the media element gets h4. Can it be changed to smaller, say h6?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

The easiest way was to create a new template for the page, add "config.concatenateCss = 0" under "Constants" and "page = PAGE
page.includeCSS.myCustomStylesheet = path_to_file" under "Setup". Then specify the h4 in the CSS.